# How to preserve 360 degree video metadata such as spherical information while ffmpeg transcoding

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtmp, hls

My objective is Live streaming 360 degree video using nginx, nginx-rtmp and ffmpeg. HLS Streaming as such working but while streaming 360 degree video, spherical data is lost at client side and 360 degree video plays side by side.
ffmpeg command to transcode

```
sudo ffmpeg -i coaster.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -strict unofficial -vprofile high  -acodec aac  -f flv rtmp://localhost/stream/coaster
```

coaster.mp4 is 360 degree video, When I play this rtmp stream using any player then it plays side by side.

However following command preservers spherical data in just normal transcoding

```
sudo ffmpeg -i coaster.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -strict unofficial -vprofile high  -acodec aac  sphirical.mp4
```